# CSS vs Jquery, sliders, animations, lightboxes... load time vs functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I find visual effects very dull and tend to import free jquery plugins to do animations. However, since I know much more CSS than javascript I really like pure css code.

The question is, is there a major advantage to not using jquery? Do I really speed up load time by eliminating jquery but adding 50 lines of CSS? Or is that totally wrong? I really have no problem using jquery, but I find myself hunting those pure css techniques because less is more.

I would like a comparison of CSS and jquery from people's experience.  And don't get on me about how jquery does much more than what CSS can do adn that they should not even be compared. I am only talking about animations and visual effects as far as CSS can go, so using jquery in the realm of css.

Last question, kind of a bonus question but the reason I am asking this in the first place. Is there a way to create a CSS slider that will loop through images no matter how many exist? In other words, instead of setting a separate time for each image to appear, can I just set a time for the next event to take place? I use php loops to fill my sliders which pull the image paths from a database, so if myself or one of my coworkers adds in too many images, the css sliders always freak out, but jquery ones handle it just fine.

I look forward to hearing everyone's opinion on this.

Comment: Could you spend some more time to help me understand what you're trying to say in less words?  ie. Specify jQuery/jQueryUI or even better $.animate()  vs pure CSS... 
Your last question kind of answers the first one's. Maybe you can also provide an example for that bonus question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are advantages and disadvantages to both CSS and jQuery (for visual effects).

### CSS

- CSS will be faster, because its layout engines (Blink, Gecko, Trident) are implemented in C++. You can still write inefficient selectors though; [see here](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) for tips on how to improve them.
- Newer [CSS3] features will not be available in IE8. You won't have access to animations or transitions, so you will have to either gracefully degrade or implement a JavaScript fallback.

  - However, one could argue that such effects are superfluous anyway.
- You don't have variables or math in CSS. Using a preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) solves this, and while you probably should be using a preprocessor anyway, it does add an extra level of complexity to your workflow, so manage it smartly.
- See also some specific [Limitations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Limitations) and [Advantages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Advantages).

### jQuery

- jQuery will be slower, because it is implemented in JavaScript.
- jQuery's load time will be improved it you load from the CDN: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">`. Lots of developers also use the CDN, so there is a good chance the client will already have a cached version of the script and get a `304 Not Modified`.
- Almost all of jQuery's [1.x branch] features should work cross-browser.
- jQuery can apply any CSS style to an element *in addition* to offering
  its own JavaScript visual effects, making it more versatile.
- Some of jQuery's visual effects use CSS (like hiding and showing), making it somewhat redundant at times. (Though jQuery also tracks the state of visibility, something that you can't do in CSS because you don't have variables or callbacks for event handlers.)

I would suggest that for visual effects, you always seek a cross-browser IE8+ CSS solution first, for speed. If such a solution is not available, use jQuery, or else settle for a simpler design / functionality.

Also keep in mind that by using jQuery, you are exchanging execution speed for development speed. You are not necessarily sacrificing any of the visual effects afforded by jQuery, because they are all still available in raw JavaScript. But you would need to re-implement them, so you may as well just use the well-tested and well-documented library that is available.

Comment: I had no idea that by loading it from their site was better than loading my own downloaded version. It makes sense though like you said with cached versions.

Answer (score 2):

```
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;        // Work time
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; // less time spent with family
-moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;    // less time spent with family
-ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;     // less time spent with family
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;      // less time spent with family
```

vs:

```
var fadeTime = 1000;                        // and all the time in the world
```

when you'll be able to do in native styles f.e:

```
.el:click{
    animate: left calc(counter * .el<@width) 0.3s "ease-in-out";
    /* where "<" is for parent :) */
}
```

...fun apart,

- **CSS3** still unmodular, lacks of event inconsistencies and unstable animation transitions,
- yet still not recognized in all living browsers,
- it's really hard to maintain <sup>(2013)</sup>,
- almost every existent CSS3 gallery uses some JS code to compensate triggers, actions etc so I think still all those *experiments* are mainly personal achievements trying to get to some sunlight.
- so you'll end up having *both* a huge CSS3 script and dependent on some JS code to handle (mainly) actiion events.

- **JS** (jQuery *is* JS) and animations, using `requestAnimationFrame` let's you tell to the browser to execute repaints when it's most appropriate, saves battery, it's paused on tab inactivity, it's handled by the browser (similar as CSS transitions/animations) and the browser can optimize it, allowing animations to be fast and wowingly smooth!
- Latest jQuery versions have already taken care to give the best performance.
- Instead of 100+ lines of CSS3 scripts, you can build a fade gallery in a couple of lines of jQuery, ok, you have to load some `kb` of library, but why not.
- Plugins you build (or download) will easily let you handle separate animation times, effects, styles, but just adding/changing one property value keeping code at minimum.
- Saves you time. Both to you, your pet and to the guy that will come after you.

<sub>Never forget to keep up with **CSS** it's awesome and the good things about it are still to come.</sub>

Comment: It could just be because I know CSS much better than JQuery but I'd say CSS is the easier option.

A CSS slider isn't that hard to build (I've done it in less than 50 lines) where as a jQuery library, plus a JQuery plug in, plus a few lines to control it seems much more complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

I find JQuery better for controlling and responding to user actions, manipulating properties in the box model, and easily accessing components on the page based on CSS. That's sort of its forte. The animation features in JQuery are pretty decent as well, though most of them are just CSS-like presets anyway.

If you're looking for a fun way to do animations without using much JQuery, and you like CSS, you should check out animate.css at https://daneden.me/animate/